# Creating XML Prefix while Serialization to Namespace Generation

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, namespaces

I want to Serialize a class to XML in C#

**My Classes:**

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader")]

public class StandardBusinessDocument
{
    public StandardBusinessDocumentHeader StandardBusinessDocumentHeader { get; set; }

    public Package Package { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.efatura.gov.tr/package-namespace")]
public class Package
{

    public Elements Elements { get; set; }

}
```

When i serialize this classes to XML

```
    XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    namespaces.Add("sh", "http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader");
    namespaces.Add("ef", "http://www.efatura.gov.tr/package-namespace");
    XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StandardBusinessDocument));

    xser.Serialize(soapwriter, new StandardBusinessDocument
    {
        StandardBusinessDocumentHeader = sbd,
        Package = new Package()
        {
            Elements = elements
        }
    }, namespaces);
```

After that, i seen the first class (**StandardBusinessDocumentHeader**) and under the nodes which has **sh prefix-namespaces**. But Pakacge always shows **sh: prefix** instead of **ef:** but on the other side the pakage shown with **ef: prefix**

I just want to add **ef: prefix** to the **Pakage** node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace for the `Package` property, so that the `Package` element is correct.

```
[XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.efatura.gov.tr/package-namespace")]
public Package Package { get; set; }
```